# Adding Logging Target Listeners to Enterprise Library Configuration Tool

Tags: configuration, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am using the logging application block from Enterprise Library 5.0 in my application. My architect wanted custom behaviour therefore I wrote my own Trace Listener which logs to a database, executing other custom code on the way.  This all works.

Now when I create this trace listener and its data class alongside the other listeners inside the Enterprise Library project it is picked up by the configuration tool when I try to add a logging target listener as a type of listener.  The problem is my architect does not want me to alter the Enterprise Library source code therefore he wants to implement the listener in our own DLL and then reference them from Enterprise Library configuration.  This also works.

My only problem is that when I do it this way the configuration tool does not pick up my listener as a type I can add.  I can edit the config file manually and it works this way but it is a requirement to be able to do this via the config tool.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get the configuration tool to find your custom trace listener (I'm assuming using full design time integration) is to place your assembly in the same directory as the configuration tool executable.